# Tangent Vector at the point $(1,2,11)$ whose projection onto the $xy$-plane is parallel to vector $1/\sqrt{10}i+3/\sqrt{10}j$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$f(x,y) = x^3y^2 + 3x + 2y$$

The gradient of $f$ at the point $(1,2)$ is $15{\bf i} + 6{\bf j}$.

${\bf u} =  \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf i} + \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf j}$

The Directional Derivative is $\dfrac{33}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Hint: The $x$ and $y$ coordinate is the same as ${\bf u}$ above.

What is the $z$ coordinate?

Comment: Isn't it just $f(1,2)=1^32^2+3(1)+2(2)=11$?

Comment: That wouldn't make sense though because the point in space is (1,2,11), and we're looking for the projection of that point or vector onto the xy plane... so theoretically the point will stay the same in x and y, with z being the only part that changes. But I can't find a way to solve for z. (1,2,z)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Now I understand what you're asking...

You seem to be looking for a vector lying on the plane tangent to $z=f(x,y)$ at the point $(x,y)=(1,2)$ whose projection is ${\bf u}$.

The equation of the tangent plane at $(x,y)=(1,2)$ is $z = 11+15(x-1)+6(y-2)$ since $f(1,2)=11$ and $\nabla f(1,2) = 15{\bf i}+6{\bf j}$.

If we move $x$ and $y$ in the ${\bf u}$-direction, we wish to know the corresponding change in $z$ (as measured by the tangent plane). So if $\Delta x = x-1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$ and $\Delta y = y-2 = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}$, what is $\Delta z = z-11$?

On the tangent plane we have $\Delta z = 15\Delta x + 6\Delta y = 15\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}+6\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}} = \dfrac{33}{\sqrt{10}}$.

Clearly ${\bf v} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf i}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf j}+\dfrac{33}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf k}$ projects onto ${\bf u}$ if we project out the ${\bf k}$-component (i.e. project out the $z$-direction = project onto the $xy$-plane).

Notice that ${\bf n}=-15{\bf i}-6{\bf j}+{\bf k}$ is a normal vector for the tangent plane (since an equivalent equation for this plane is: $-15(x-1)-6(y-2)+(z-11)=0$). Since ${\bf n}$ and ${\bf v}$ are perpendicular:
$${\bf n} {\bf\cdot} {\bf v} = \left(-15{\bf i}-6{\bf j}+{\bf k}\right){\bf\cdot}\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf i}+\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf j}+\dfrac{33}{\sqrt{10}}{\bf k}\right) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(-15(1)+(-6)3+33)=0$$
we have that ${\bf v}$ is parallel to the tangent plane (i.e. it's a tangent vector).